# How do I process below foreach loop with multiple thereading in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, c#-4.0

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in grdSearch.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox cbox = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("chkRow");
        if (cbox.Checked == true)
        {
              //Do some Task
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do and what problem you think parallel execution will solve.

Comment: I am calling the webservice inside the loop, request data is from grid view row . the current request to webservice is processed serially for each response it takes around 2-3 minutes,so for 50 request it will take around 150 minutes. I want to execute all the grid row parallel so i can acheive the results in 2-3 minutes.

Comment: If one service call takes 2-3 minutes (!) to process, then parallelizing the calls to that service most likely isn't going to solve anything, as the server (or one it depends on, like the database server) probably already is running under maximum load. If you have such long-running operations (and are you waiting for the result of that operation in this code?), you could use some kind of (message) queue and a background process like a Windows Service that pops requests off this queue does the processing.

Comment: I hope database query runs parallel in sql server. the response time is higher due to the query time is higher, not probably due to heavy load on db. So if 50 request goes simultaneously , all the request will response almost same time(I have tested this with two  application). Sorry but we don't have permission to use windows service. And also the reducing the response time is important for me, your approach will take same time, only thing is, it will run in background.

Answer (score 1):

you can use parallel.foreach for the same....below is a sample of parallel.foreach

```
Parallel.ForEach(nonGenericCollection.Cast<object>(),
    currentElement =>
    {
    });
```

Comment: Can you please rewrite the above code using parallel foreach loop.

Comment: I got the exact answer i was looking the other thread in stackoverflow. Sorry I am not authorize to post the link with regards to my reputation count here. But i will post the solution here in case anybody is looking for same scenario. [Solution Code] 
   

grdSearch.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().Where(
      r => ((CheckBox)r.FindControl("chkRow")).Checked).AsParallel().ForAll(row =>
{
  //Do smth
});

Don't forget to use- using System.Linq; 
This took me another 3 days to figure out.